# Checkout Maven project with subclipse in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, m2e, subclipse

I want to checkout a multi-module Maven project in Eclipse (I am using Subclipse). When I use the usual checkout mechanism from the "SVN Repository Exploring" perspective, only the parent project is checked out and the modules are not generated as Eclipse projects. I found different advice on Stackoverflow and google, but the results are not satisfactory:

1. After the checkout, one can go to "Import" and import the modules into the Eclipse workspace. This works, but is an awkward extra step (I do not want to tell our 100+ developers that the simple checkout mechanism does not work anymore when we use Maven)
2. Use some "m2e-connector": Unfortunately, I cannot open the connection in "Install m2e connectors", maybe due to company internet restrictions. Furthermore, I could not find any reliable information if these connectors are still in use and supported.

So I hope that somebody using multi-module projects in Eclipse (Kepler, Luna, Mars) can tell me a usable, up-to-date solution for this.

Comment: I use the Subversive plugin currently. Does the "Check out as Maven Project from SCM" wizard show up in your Import or your New Project options, or maybe when you right click in the Repository Browser tree? I have several Maven-specific plugins, and it's hard to know sometimes which one is responsible for which view.

Comment: I do use multi-module Maven projects. They all load as projects when the parent project is loaded, but they're schizo: source control operations are only available on subprojects when accessed as subfolders of the Maven parent. Eclipse operations (things depending on classpath, for instance) are only available when accessed via their  individual project icons.

Comment: @nclark: In the "Check out as Maven Project from SCM", I do not have any connectors to choose from (SCM Url). If I try to install one, I only find one for Subversive, not Subclipse.